# Finding total amount of paths in a triangle grid (iterative without recursion)

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration, directed-graph, triangle

i have a given a triangle grid:

[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POcnq.png)

For every point (i,j) with i+j being even:

[Given recursive function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1BIc.png)

Now i need to write a **iterative** function that finds all possible paths from (0,0) to the point (2n,0) given that n ∈ N.

So my idea, written in pseudo code:

```
def path (i,j):
       
    paths = set()
    A = [ 1 for  x in range(j)]
    
    for x in range (i - len(A)):
          A.append (last)-(-1)
          A.append (-1)
    set.append(path)
 
    for i in range (i!):
          candidate = permutate(A)
          for i in range(len(A)):
              if sum (A [1: i]) < 0
                  break
          Paths.append(candidate)
    return len(paths)
```

i need to count the total amount of paths possible to (2n,0)

Comment: Do you need to count the paths or return a list of paths?

Comment: @Dave I need to count the total possible paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a more mathy note, this problem is equivalent to a more famous problem- balancing parenthesis. Ever step `up-right` is a `(` and ever step `down-right` is a `)`, with `n` parenthesis pairs, how many valid sequences of parenthesis are there?

The answer for `n` is the `n`th catalan number, which is `nck(2n, n) - nck(2n, n+1)` (`nck` being "n choose k"). In python, this comes out to-

```py
from math import comb

def catalan(n):
    return comb(2*n, n) - comb(2*n, n+1)
```

So the answer to "How many distinct shortest paths from (0, 0) to (2n, 0) through my triangular grid are there?" is `catalan(n)`.

Comment: So: ​
     $$ C(2n,0) = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n} $$     ?

Comment: @CWT_Simon no- if you expand it out, you get `(2n)!/(n!n!) - (2n)!/((n-1)!(n+1)!)`

Answer (score 0):

For every node other than (0,0), the number of ways to reach that node is the sum of the number of ways to meet its immediate predecessors. There is one way to reach (0,0).

Start with (0,0) -> 1, and a queue containing (1,1). On each iteration, take the node at the front of the queue, update it to be the sum of its predecessors, and add any successors that have all predecessors calculated to the end of the queue.

```
(0,0) -> 1; queue = [(1,1)]
(1,1) -> 1; queue = [(2,2), (2,0)]
(2,2) -> 1; queue = [(2,0), (3,3)]
(2,0) -> 1; queue = [(3,3), (3,1)]
(3,3) -> 1; queue = [(3,1), (4,4)]
(3,1) -> 2; queue = [(4,4), (4,0), (4,2)]
... and so on
```

Comment: You could omit the queue and just go from left to right (resolving all x-values <= x=k before moving on to x=k+1)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math

A = []
def C_iterativ(n):
    C = [[0 for _ in range(n+2)] for _ in range(2*n+1)]
    C[0][0] = 1
    for i in range(2*n+1):
        for j in range(n+1):
            C[i][j] += C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j+1]
    return C[2*n][0]

for i in range(20):
    print(int(1/(i+1)*math.factorial(2*i)/(math.factorial(i)**2)) == C_iterativ(i))
```

---

Recursive solution:

```py
def C_memo(i, j, memo={}):
    if (i, j) in memo:
        return memo[(i, j)]
    if i == j == 0:
        result = 1
    elif i == 0 and j > 0:
        result = 0
    elif i > 0 and j == 0:
        result = C_memo(i-1, 1, memo)
    elif i > 0 and j > 0:
        result = C_memo(i-1, j-1, memo) + C_memo(i-1, j+1, memo)
    memo[(i, j)] = result
    return result
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74834667/3) to the question [Finding total amount of paths in a triangle grid (iterative without recursion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834667/finding-total-amount-of-paths-in-a-triangle-grid-iterative-without-recursion) by the OP [CWT_Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20801616/cwt-simon) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>